# „menuinterface.Menu.exit' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null“

Tags: c#, xna

How I can use Exit() in another class? I want to use it in the Intro class, but I always get that „menuinterface.Menu.exit' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null“ error message. What is wrong?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private IState currentState;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        currentState = new Intro();
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {       
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        currentState.Load(Content);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        currentState.Update(gameTime);         
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        currentState.Render(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public interface IState
    {
        void Load(ContentManager content);
        void Update(GameTime gametime);
        void Render(SpriteBatch batch);
    }

public class Intro : IState
{
    private IState currentState;
    private Game1 exit;
    Texture2D introscreen;

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        introscreen = content.Load<Texture2D>("intro");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
          currentState = new Menu();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            exit.Exit();
    }

    public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(introscreen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720), Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful, if not a duplicate of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811155/field-xxx-is-never-assigned-to-and-will-always-have-its-default-value-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
public class Intro : IState
{
    private IState currentState;
    private Game1 exit;
    Texture2D introscreen;

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        introscreen = content.Load<Texture2D>("intro");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
          currentState = new Menu();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            exit.Exit(); // ---- this object does not exist
    }

    public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(introscreen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720), Color.White);
    }
}
```

In this class you are declaring an object called `exit` but this value is never assigned.  You need to instantiate the object before you use it.  In your case, I would add the following constructor to resolve your problem.

```
public Intro(Game1 game)
{
    exit = game;
}
```

Comment: But will it do what's expected (exit the game)?

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following error message in Game1 class:
'menuinterface.Intro' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments 

What argument should I add between the brackets of this line in Game1 class: currentState = new Intro();

Comment: @Andy: when you are creating your new `Intro` object you need to do it like this:  `currentState = new Intro(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign anything to your `exit` object, which appears to be of type `Game`, so this is why you get this error. But why do you need this `exit` object in the first place?

If you want to quit the game after pressing Escape, use `Exit()` method. It doesn't require you to use it like in your code. It is as simple as this:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    // ...
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {            
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();  

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I get this error message: The name 'Exit' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You're trying to execute this method -not- from within the main Game class. Put the whole `if (kbstate ...` thing inside your Game's `Update` method.

Comment: Is it not better to write the Exit() into the Intro class? I just want to quit the game after pressing Escape during the intro or the menu.

Comment: You'll have to check if the game is in the intro screen. Like `if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) && gameState == "intro screen") Exit()`.